# Django instance - Combine two attribute values in model

Tags: django, instance

Can someone tell me how to combine two or more attribute values of in another field by using instance?

`Models.py`:

```
    fn_id = models.ForeignKey(FilemNumber, null=True, blank=True)
    ln_id = models.ForeignKey(LineNumber, null=True, blank=True)
    pn_id = models.ForeignKey(PhotoNumber, null=True, blank=True)

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to combine fn_id, ln_id and pn_id and save the combination of the three values into field title.

Comment: Why exactly do you need it? Did you consider just using a property?

Comment: @IamMoon why don't you collect three fields `fn_id, ln_id, pn_id` into Model and get a OneToOneField to it.

Comment: @VuongHoang how to do it? I'm sorry i'm new to django and don't know the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
from django import models

class BaseModel(models.Model):
    fn_id = models.ForeignKey(FilemNumber, null=True, blank=True)
    ln_id = models.ForeignKey(LineNumber, null=True, blank=True)
    pn_id = models.ForeignKey(PhotoNumber, null=True, blank=True)


class YourModel(models.Model):
    common = models.OneToOneField(BaseModel)

    # I suppose that you want to get title, so let define title method
    # if obj is an instance of YourModel, you can access title like this:
    # obj.title
    @property
    def title(self):
        return '{}{}{}{}'.format(self.id, self.common.fn_id,
                                 self.common.ln_id, self.common.pn_id)
```

Lets read this article: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield

Comment: i want to save the combination of the values... for example fn_id 12345, ln_id LN8N, and pn_id 5432 so i want to save it in title like this : 
12345LN8N5432

Comment: You can use above models as following example:
`common = BaseModel(fn_id=fn_obj, ln_id=ln_obj, pn_id=pn_obj)`

`common.save()`

`obj = YourModel(title='your title here', common=common)`

`obj.save()`

Comment: Then, i need to create another model for title? does it mean that the value will be save in common's field and not in title's field?

Comment: You should give a detail of what you want when asking a question. In your case, i think you don't need title field.

Comment: If you absolutely must have the calculated title written to the DB then do it at the time you insert or update a record. Otherwise just use Vuong's @property method to generate a title attribute which you can then use just like a 'real' field.